# Windows 8 stuck on boot screen after installing VirtualBox

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, freeze

So I installed the new VirtualBox earlier, did some more work on my PC, and restarted my PC 2 horus after the installation, and it is now stuck on the booting screen(blue Windows logo, and a loading circle). I try to get into safe mode(shift + tapping f8) but it just can't. I've unplugged the mouse, power source and the battery, but still no help. Any ideas?

Comment: Windows 8 should provide an option to boot into Safe Mode after 2 failed attempts to load Windows.  Have you tried leaving the computer on the blue screen?

Comment: It doesn't in my case. Yes I have - for about 30 minutes.

Comment: @Ramhound I know that there is a way to change Windows 8 to boot in the legacy method (operating system list at boot time and ability to hold F8 at startup to access advanced options). This is the default on Windows Server 2012.

Comment: But it can't be used in this situation. It is best to change your boot option to Legacy after you fix the problem in case something like this happens again.

Comment: Try booting from your Windows 8 install disc. When you are asked to "Install Now", click "Repair your Computer". What happens if you pick that option?

Comment: @gparyani - You need access to a bootable system to change it to that mode, and that mode would be enabled, only until it was disabled.  The 2 failed attempts should should bring up the option, but I will be honest, how you get to safe mode with Windows 8 isn't well documented ( it was different durning the beta process for it ).  Basically they changed the process, and I personally, have not found the correct documentation that tells you how to boot into safe mode with Windows 8/Windows 8.1

Comment: @Ramhound You hold the Shift key when clicking Restart, and the Advanced Options screen will show up after the reboot, at which point you can choose Safe Mode. But again, you can only do this from a properly working system. That's why I suggested to the OP that he should change his boot mode to Legacy after the problem is fixed so that it works the same way as it has in previous versions of Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound But I do believe that you can access Startup Repair by inserting the installation disc as described in my above comment.

Comment: @gparyani - I don't doubt you can.  The problem is that most people do not have a Windows 8 installation key if they have OEM hardware that came with Windows 8.  Even if they did upgrade, its possible to upgrade to Windows 8, without creating a .iso file.

Comment: @Ramhound I do believe that Microsoft provides ISOs for Windows 8, and the repair features can be used without having to enter a product key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert your Windows 8 installation disc and boot from it. When asked to "Install Now", click "Repair your Computer". Then, launch Startup Repair to fix your problem.

After Startup Repair fixes your problem, I suggest that you change it so that it boots up as earlier versions of Windows have (F8 for startup options and OS list before booting Windows). To do that, open an elevated command prompt and type:

```
bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy legacy
```

To change it back to the standard method, type:

```
bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy standard
```